# Cannot find module 'node-gcm'

Tags: node.js

Im attempting to get Push notifications working with Android. Im following the tutorial [here](http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/). It require installation of the node-gcm module of node.js. I installed this with the following command:

```
sudo npm install -g node-gcm
```

I have a file called notify.js. I run this with:

```
node notify.js
```

But I'm always getting the error:

```
module.js:333
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'node-gcm'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:331:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:273:25)
at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
at require (module.js:373:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/PushPlay/notify.js:1:73)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:490:10)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you've done a global install of the module, sometimes you need to create a symlink to the global module. Try `npm link node-gcm`.

Also try and install node-gcm without the global switch (`npm install node-gcm`), if it works locally you'll know it's an issue with the global install.

Comment: +1. Global installation is for **CLIs** and indeed makes ONLY a package's CLIs globally available (via symlinking to `/usr/local/bin` on Unix-like systems) - using a global package **programmatically** (generally not recommended) ALWAYS requires symlinking it into the local project (as a pseudo-local package) with `npm link <name>`. Conversely, on Unix-like systems, if you want to run a *local* package's CLI, use `$(npm bin)/<localCli>`

Comment: If you are creating a serious project, you should make sure that your dependencies are in your package.json. You can achieve this by installing with `npm install node-gcm --save`.